Missing OSM Restrictions in Bounding Box Query After Importing with osm2pgsql
I’m using osm2pgsql to import OpenStreetMap (OSM) data into a PostgreSQL database for analysis. Despite configuring and importing the data correctly, I’m not seeing all the expected restrictions within a specified bounding box.
Setup and Configuration:
osm2pgsql Command:
osm2pgsql -U postgres -W -d osm_data -H localhost -s -G --number-processes 30 -C 102400 dach-latest.osm.pbf

Modifications to default.style:
node,way   restriction                    text         linear
node,way   restriction:conditional        text         linear

PostgreSQL Database Schema:
planet_osm_line table includes columns like restriction and restriction:conditional, both of type text.
The geometry column way is of type geometry(LineString, 3857).
SQL Query:
I use the following query to fetch distinct restrictions within a bounding box:
SELECT DISTINCT restriction, "restriction:conditional"
FROM planet_osm_line
WHERE highway IN ('motorway', 'trunk', 'primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'unclassified',
                  'residential', 'motorway_link', 'trunk_link', 'primary_link', 'secondary_link', 'tertiary_link')
AND ST_Intersects(way, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(10.91492, 47.41136, 13.41705, 49.07207, 4326), 3857));

Issue:
 restriction   |              restriction:conditional               
-----------------+----------------------------------------------------
 only_right_turn | 
                 | restriction:conditional=no_parking @ (19:00-06:00)
                 | 
(3 rows)

I have verified the presence of more restrictions within this bounding box using an external tool https://ahorn.lima-city.de/tr/  which shows a greater variety of restrictions.
What I’ve Tried:

Updating Data: Ensured my database is up-to-date with the latest OSM data.

Query Adjustments: Simplified and expanded the query to include all potential restrictions without the highway filter.


Question:
What could be causing the discrepancy between the restrictions visible in the external tool and those retrieved from my PostgreSQL database? Are there any additional configurations or steps I should consider to ensure all relevant restrictions are captured?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Update
I modified a lua script I found here :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/osm2pgsql-dev/osm2pgsql/master/flex-config/compatible.lua
to include restrictions:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Andreas4242/Andreas_file_tools/main/compatible.lua
Im sure its not correct way to handle this.
The modified Lua script helps read the data into the PostGIS database using Flex, but I’m still not sure if this is the correct way to handle the restrictions. I imagine it should be possible to invalidate the connections that are not allowed somehow.

Most of the restrictions are relations: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:restriction - did you consider this? Your config does only process the ways when you define linear as type

yes I see. I just don't know how to handle then.

EPSG:3857 has units of metres and I see that you are transforming your envelope to 3857 (from Decimal Degrees). Can you confirm that the units of way are in metres as well?
The documentation allows the intersection of geometry to geometry and geography to geography but not a mix.
boolean ST_Intersects( geometry geomA , geometry geomB );
boolean ST_Intersects( geography geogA , geography geogB );
If way is metres, you could coerce it to by adding
AND ST_Intersects(way::geometry, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(10.91492, 47.41136, 13.41705, 49.07207, 4326), 3857));

from what I know, they are in meters also. But running the query the reult seems to be the same with or without ::geometry
